# Facebook profile page - How to add shortcut to your "likes nav"

Tags: facebook

I've got an app, that I need to make shortcut to on profile page in likes nav (there where photos, likes etc boxes appear.). How you make app "addable" or add it to your page?

PS: I haven't found any tutorial on how you do it. Maybe i didn't know where to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it possible. You can to [create a custom Facebook tab](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/26330/How-to-Create-Custom-Tabs-for-Facebook-Business-Pages.aspx) for your page, then in the tab place something like this:

```
<script>top.location.href='http://www.location-of-my-short-link.com';</script>
```

You can customize the name, thumbnail and placement of the icon/tab and when users click on it..it takes them to the app, which forward them no to your short via Javascript.

Comment: App i want to link to is created uner same user. So My buisness page is admin of app. I think step 6 is what I need. Still dont know how to proceed.

Comment: You (not your page) is admin of the app, i think.

Comment: Not sure tbh. I got a creditentials from my client. When I log i cannot use facebook as anyone else.

Comment: Solution from your link worked. I had to create a special (step #6) link with APPID and link, open it and voila! Tab appeared on page.

Strange there is no interface to add page tab from facebook level.